# Print detailed stack trace for parsing json

Tags: python, pytest

I have a set of data from json that I open and compare with another set of data from csv.

```
assert data1_json1 == data1_csv1
assert data2_json1 == data2_csv2
assert data3_json1 == data3_csv3
assert data4_json1 == data4_csv4
.......
assert data1_json2 == data1_csv10
assert data2_json2 == data2_csv11
assert data3_json2 == data3_csv12
assert data4_json2 == data4_csv13
.......
```

It works well till the time I need to get detailed response. I can use `try` `except` for one set of data, but I don't know how to use it for all asserts without code duplication.

```
try:
   assert data1_json == data1_csv
except AssertionError:
   raise AssertionError('Json: ' + data1_json, 'CSV: ' + data1_csv)
```

Comment: You could make two lists and do `for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b):` and put the try statement in that

Answer (score 0):

You can send the message along with assert.
For example,

```
try:
    assert data1_json == data1_csv, "Json: "+data1_json+" CSV: "+data1_csv
    assert data2_json == data2_csv, "Json: "+data2_json+" CSV: "+data2_csv
    ...
except AssertionError as e:
    print(e)
```

That e will display "Json: "+data1_json+" CSV: "+data1_csv

In further easy mode, pass the values in a tuple and retrieve it in AssertionError mode

```
try:
    assert data1_json == data1_csv, (data1_json,data1_csv)
    assert data2_json == data2_csv, (data2_json,data2_csv)
    ...
except AssertionError as e:
    output = list(e[0])
    print("Json: "+output[0]+" CSV: "+output[1])
```